# After disconnecting mapped network drive, cant reconnect

Tags: windows-7, samba, smb

After I right click on a mapped network drive and click disconnect, I cannot reconnect. It tells me that the location is unavailable.

Comment: How are you trying to reconnect? From within the Network Places screen, or directly? Can you ping the destination?

Comment: I have another share on that same computer,(just a different folder) and I can connect to it. It is not within the network places, it is within the "Computer Screen" since it is a mapped drive.